# replace line breaks in CSV

Tags: php, regex, csv, preg-replace

I have an issue regarding converting a CSV-String into an array.

```
INV;165;1;0;1 Username;0;10000;"Here is multiline-text.

with line-breaks:

";20 Offen;0,00
INV;166;1;0;1 Username2;0;10000;"Here is another multiline-text.

with line-breaks:

";20 Offen;0,00
```

I tried to split up the fields with str_getcsv, but the problem is, that the delimiter only occurs in one field and the function is splitting up the multiline-fields also.

My solution was to first convert the line-breaks by preg_replace, but I'm not getting into it.
Here's my regex to only replace the line-breaks enclosed by ;" and "; :

```
/(;")(.*)(\n)(.*)(";)/
```

This pattern does actually match only the first line-break.
Could anyone give me a hint to do this job?

Thank you in advance.

Here is the original CSV:

```
CMXINV;165;1;0;1 Felix Hirschberg;0;10000;Herr;;Max;Muster;Company;;Street;123;City;DE;(0 40) 6 25 6;;(0 40) 6 25 6;mail@muster.de;;;;;;;;0;20121217;20121217;1 Sofort ohne Abzug;EUR;1 Agentur;0 ;0,00;;"Vielen Dank für Ihren Auftrag.

Vereinbarungsgemäß berechnen wir Ihnen:

";"Mit besten Grüßen


Invoice Man";;0;0;0;0;;20 Offen;0,00;;0 ;0,00;0,00;;EXW;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;2;;Project: Test-Project;;0,000;0,00;1,000;0,00;0,00;0;0;0;0;0
CMXINV;165;2;0;1 Felix Hirschberg;0;10000;Herr;;Max;Muster;Company;;Street;123;City;DE;(0 40) 6 25 6;;(0 40) 6 25 6;mail@muster.de;;;;;;;;0;20121217;20121217;1 Sofort ohne Abzug;EUR;1 Agentur;0 ;0,00;;"Vielen Dank für Ihren Auftrag.

Vereinbarungsgemäß berechnen wir Ihnen:

";"Mit besten Grüßen


Invoice Man";;0;0;0;0;;20 Offen;0,00;;0 ;0,00;0,00;;EXW;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;0;1;"- job1 (1h)
- job2 (1h)
- job3 (0,75h)
- job4 (1h)
- job5 (0,5h)";HR;3,25;100,00;1,00;0,00;325,00;1;0;0;0;0
MESSAGE;S;210053;INVOICE_GET hat 1 Datensätze zurückgegeben
MESSAGE;S;204020;Datenübertragung erfolgreich. Es wurden 1 Datensätze verarbeitet.
```

Comment: Is this a valid CSV at all? Could something like that be opened via Excel? If not, why bother – just create (or let create) a valid format that could be used from any software. If you need line breaks in your content you should think about using XML instead of CSV as data format for communication across multiple applications.

Comment: Problem is, the CSV is delivered by an API wich I can't modify. And yes, these files can be opened via Excel.

Comment: I guess you need a multi-line identifier to make your regexp work over multiple lines of text/code. See also: http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: can you paste the original CVS file ?

Comment: @alinsoar pasted in my original post

Comment: in your original post you posted cvs file mixed with your comments. this would make me guess what the cvs is, so my solution may not have worked on the original file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
/;"(([^"]*)([\r\n])+([^"]*))+"/im
```

This will match the text before and after every newline within the `;"` delimiters. 
The second match will be the preceding text, and the fourth match will be the following text.

Note that I have left off the last ';' to ensure that this will still match if the multi-line value is the last in the line.

Comment: thanks! That is already a good way to go, but I've that issue, that only the last \n in an CSV-Column is replaced. I've fields with more than one line break.

Comment: `preg_replace` doesn't play nicely with nested patterns. Perhaps try `preg_match_all`, and loop through all the results?

Answer (score 1):

According to user comments in php manual both [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) should handle newlines correctly.

You probably should take an advantage of those implementation (they should have already solve any possible issue you can come accross).

---

#### Edit: own parser

Or you could write your own parser (based on comment):

```
// Browse file one character after another
while (false !== ($c = fgetc($fp))) {
    // We are not inside the value, newline = new row
    if( ($c == "\n") || ($c == "\r")){
       // Newline, add to result
       continue;
    }

    // Whitespace? continue, do nothing
    if( ctype_space( $c)){
        continue;
    }

    // Okay, now we can use switch
    switch( $c){
        case ',':
            // Add empty value
            break;

        // Escaped value
        case '"':
        case "'":
            $escapeChar = $c;
            $prevChar = '';
            $value = '';

            while( false !== ($c = fgetc($fp))){
                // We just hit and end of escaped sequence, check escaped val by \
                if( ($c == $escapeChar) && ($c != '\\') ){
                   break;
                }

                // If we got \ and prev value is \ = "blah blah \\"
                // Prevent escape escape character of being guessed incorrectly
                if( ($c == '\\') && ($prevChar == '\\')){
                    $prevChar = '';
                } else {
                    $prevChar = $c;
                }

                $value .= $c;
            }

            // $value is your value
            break;

        // Normal, non escaped value:
        default:
            $value = '';
            while( false !== ($c = fgetc($fp))){
                if( ($c == ',') || ($c == '\n') || ($c == '\r')){
                    break;
                }
                $value .= $c;
            }

            // $value = your field value
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: I was getting in  trouble with that functions, because some fields are enclosed and some are not.

Comment: @FelixHirschberg I've added parsers for you

Answer (score 0):

If you have the CSV input in a file, you can just use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv), which will handle multi-line entries just fine.

If the CSV input is in a string, you can use the special [`php://temp`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) I/O stream to efficiently pass it to `fgetcsv()`:

```
$fp = fopen( 'php://temp', 'w+' );
fputs( $fp, $csv );
rewind( $fp );
$data = fgetcsv( $fp, 0, ';', '"' );
fclose( $fp );
```